# Not able to insert data into database

Tags: mysql, django

This is an excerpt of my **view.py**

```
def routineInput(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    today = datetime.now
    form = CreateRoutine(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/saved/')
else:
    form = CreateRoutine()

return render(request, 'todo/croutine.html', {'form': form})
```

So the idea is that I have a simple input form where I put a name into it and it should push this name into a table in my database. My code is coming thorough and it shows my /todo/saved page but my POST request doesn't seem to get sent to my table or my table is rejecting it or something.

My **model.py** class:

```
class Todolist(models.Model):
name =  models.TextField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving your form data.

do

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/saved/')
```

Comment: This works assuming the form is a ModelForm. Otherwise it has to be handled by a save some other place.

Comment: Yep, agreed. Made an assumptions that the op was using model forms